# copy build configuration to release configuration (Eclipse)

Tags: c++, eclipse, build

Once I have set the include directories and linking directories for an Eclipse project in debug configuration, is there an easy way to copy them over to the release configuration without entering them in again manually (or vice versa)?

Answer (score 3):

In the project properties, in the field Configuration, you should choose between Debug, Release and All Configuration. If you select "All configurations", everything you set will be applied to Debug and Release.
The issue is that, sometimes, include and linking directories depends on the configuration. For instance : ".../Include/Debug" or ".../Include/Release". In this case, you can still use "All Configurations" and write ".../Include/${ConfigName}"

ConfigName is an Eclipse variable that is automatically preset to Debug or Release according to the configuration.
${Var} means that you want to include the value of Var. In the example above, the string will be understand by Eclipse as ".../Include/Debug" or ".../Include/Release" according to the configuration.

You can add your own variable in Properties / C/C++ Build / Build Variables, in order to do more powerful things.